# Find and Replace Recursive in xml file for blank spaces in email address

Tags: scripting

We are migrating an old environment to a new environment. The email addresses in the old environment could have blank spaces at the front or end. However, with the new environment, this is not allowed.

Example File:

`<PEOPLE objectclass="[objPeople, objlwsnRMResource, top]" id="jdoe">
            <ID><![CDATA[jdoe]]></ID>
            <ALLOWJOBQUEUE><![CDATA[N]]></ALLOWJOBQUEUE>
            <GROUP><![CDATA[ESS Employee]]></GROUP>
            <LASTNAME><![CDATA[Doe                       ]]></LASTNAME>
            <NAME><![CDATA[John Doe]]></NAME>
            <FIRSTNAME><![CDATA[John      ]]></FIRSTNAME>
            <EMAIL><![CDATA[JohnDoe@someplace.com                              ]]></EMAIL>
        </PEOPLE>`

From here you can see that it has xml tags.
and there are whitespaces in places in the tags like LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, and EMAIL. However, I don't want the whitespaces like in between name like in NAME tag "John Doe". I want to keep it like that.

How do I take the trailing whitespaces out of a file after a certain tag name, and save that file in place, or copy it to another file.

Desired results:

`<PEOPLE objectclass="[objPeople, objlwsnRMResource, top]" id="jdoe">
            <ID><![CDATA[jdoe]]></ID>
            <ALLOWJOBQUEUE><![CDATA[N]]></ALLOWJOBQUEUE>
            <GROUP><![CDATA[ESS Employee]]></GROUP>
            <LASTNAME><![CDATA[Doe]]></LASTNAME>
            <NAME><![CDATA[John Doe]]></NAME>
            <FIRSTNAME><![CDATA[John]]></FIRSTNAME>
            <EMAIL><![CDATA[JohnDoe@someplace.com]]></EMAIL>
        </PEOPLE>
<PEOPLE objectclass="[objPeople, objlwsnRMResource, top]" id="jdoe2">
            <ID><![CDATA[jdoe2]]></ID>
            <ALLOWJOBQUEUE><![CDATA[N]]></ALLOWJOBQUEUE>
            <GROUP><![CDATA[ESS Employee]]></GROUP>
            <LASTNAME><![CDATA[Doe]]></LASTNAME>
            <NAME><![CDATA[Jane Doe]]></NAME>
            <FIRSTNAME><![CDATA[Jane]]></FIRSTNAME>
            <EMAIL><![CDATA[JaneDoe@someplace.com]]></EMAIL>
        </PEOPLE>`

Anyone ever do anything like this?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample part of the LDIF file, and clearly identify which line(s) would need to be processed as you describe. For example, would you want whitespace removal on just the `mail:` lines, or on other (or even all) lines? It's a pretty trivial job with something like `sed`; have you actually tried anything at all?

Comment: Here is an example:

Comment: <PEOPLE objectclass="[objPeople, RMResource, top]" id="jdoe">            
            <ID><![CDATA[jdoe]]></ID>
            <ALLOWJOBQUEUE><![CDATA[N]]></ALLOWJOBQUEUE>
            <GROUP><![CDATA[ESS Employee]]></GROUP>
            <LASTNAME><![CDATA[Doe                       ]]></LASTNAME>
            <ISDISABLED><![CDATA[NO]]></ISDISABLED>
            <NAME><![CDATA[John Doe]]></NAME>
            <FIRSTNAME><![CDATA[John       ]]></FIRSTNAME>
            <EMAIL><![CDATA[JohnDoe@someplace.com                               ]]></EMAIL>
        </PEOPLE>

Comment: As you can see from the above code, some areas I don't want to remove spaces. Like between the users full name <NAME><![CDATA[John Doe]]></NAME>

Comment: But I do want to remove whitespace in places like. Email:<EMAIL><![CDATA[JohnDoe@someplace.com                       ]]></EMAIL> and First and Last Name.

Comment: This file information when I enter it in here doesn't show the full extent of the whitespaces, but there is a lot of whitespace after the email, first name and last name

Comment: That's not [LDIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format).

Comment: Roaima, correct it is not ldif. It is an xml file that I later convert to ldif, but you get my point hopefully.

Comment: You described it initially as LDIF. It's still wrongly described as LDIF in the title. If it had been LDIF it would have been a trivial fix. But it isn't LDIF so please don't call it LDIF.

Comment: Fine roaima. I changed it in the description. I would like to take the whitespaces out of certain tags in an xml file.

Comment: (1) At the risk of being pedantic, what about this question is recursive? (2) With questions like this, we generally expect askers to *show* the expected/desired results, and not just describe them.

Comment: G-Man, I modified the question with expected/desired results. Also, it is recursive in the fact that there can be multiple people tags as shown above. I used the examples of John and Jane Doe. However, there could be thousands of people tag users. The script would need to recursively go through each of the people tag users, modify - Firstname, Lastname, and email only for each.

Comment: None of that requirement is _recursive_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` to remove whitespace leading up to the `]]` sequence:

```
sed 's/ *]]/]]/g' file.xml
```

Here, the regular expression "`*]]`" matches any space ("") zero or more times ("`*`"), followed by the literal "`]]`". Any such matches are then replaced with "`]]`". The result is written to *stdout*, where you can redirect it in any suitable manner.

If you have a suitable version of `sed` you can choose to use "`\s`" instead of "" to indicate *any whitespace character* (i.e. not just spaces, but also tabs and other non-printing characters).

Comment: I get it. I used your code snippet exactly, and it worked! Thank you! Thank you! That is what I was looking for!